# Solr: Load custom transformer jars at runtime using blob store API

Tags: solr, blob, solrcloud, dataimporthandler

I'm trying to use solr's upjars feature for loading custom transformers but it's not working, The upjars feature worked for custom `ResponseWriters` and `QueryParsers` but not for transformers.

Are transformers not included in the upjars feature? 
Is writing a Custom `dataimporthandler` to load it with the transformers at runtime the only solution?

Comment: Which version of solr is been using..?

Comment: I'm using version 5.3.1